# Nuxt 3 + Vite svg icon dynamic import error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have like this component in my Nuxt 3 application:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="icon" />
</template>

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  keepalive: true,
})

const props = defineProps({
  svg: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

const icon = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* @vite-ignore */`@/assets/icons/${props.svg}.svg`))
</script>
```

Error message from terminal:

```
WARN  21:16:15 [vite] warning: Unexpected token (1:14)
Plugin: vite:dynamic-import-vars
File: D:/Development/Projects/nuxt-app/components/SvgIcon.vue
```

[image]

[image]

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations

Import svg files works, but I have warnings in my terminal. How I can fix errors?

Comment: Hm, do you mind taking a screenshot of the error in your terminal please? Like what you have around it. Could be TS error or an ESlint one, it's too zoomed as of right now IMO.

Comment: Added more errors from terminal @kissu

Comment: You did the heavy lifting by yourself here! Not sure why the `ignore` is not working but you already have the whole solution. The bundler cannot analyze it, hence it gives you a warning. If you're fine with it, ignore the warning and continue your journey.

Comment: This does not suit me, so I wanted to open a question here about this. @kissu

Comment: The warning or the fact that the bundler cannot know the size of the asset?

Comment: Couldn't pinpoint the exact cause of the error. I will now try to create a demo project to demonstrate the error. @kissu

Comment: The first one so? It's probably a minor bug so that it's not picked by your codebase here. Probably something to feedback to the core team of Vite by creating a [repro] and filing an issue. For the bundler part, it can't do anything magic to analyze it's size but you understand that already I guess.

Comment: It's not an error. It is a warning and it's caused by your dynamic importing. Vite wants to warn the user that it can not analyze this file. So it can not do some actions like bundling, and tree shaking... for this file. Sometimes, it will be a problem when you import a js file. But in this case, the SVG file is OK. So I think you don't need to care about it.

Comment: @Duannx it will still properly bundle, the bundler is just not able to detect how big it will be because it's dynamic and you don't have "on-runtime analytical bundle size analysis" for obvious reasons. A solution would be to give a determined array of SVG and pick one of them, that way Vite would know in advance the size of all of them. But I guess that OP wants them to be fully dynamic.

Comment: @kissu Just now I see to Vite documentation and found description about [dynamic import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import) where says: "Note that variables only represent file names **one level deep**. If file is `'foo/bar'`, the import would fail."

Comment: @AndreasHunter interesting, didn't knew about that! Seems kinda logic at the same time (I guess).

Comment: In my case I also import icons from subdirectory like this `'subfolder/icon'` @kissu

Comment: Do you have any ideas for rewriting the component to avoid such warnings? @kissu

Comment: Sorry, I don't know there. I mean, if your import works fine, you could just omit the warning as move along. Otherwise, I'm not sure how to fix that one but Vite's Discord is plenty of pretty good people on the subject that could help you figuring out how to fix that issue.

Comment: @kissu How can vite properly bundle these kinds of files? Because Vite will only knows what file you want to import in the runtime (when the user using your app). At that time all the bundling processes had already been done.